# Working root method for Alcatel OT Pixi7 l213?

Tags: rooting

I Want to root my Alcatel OneTouch Pixi 7 (l213). Android 4.4.2

I tried adb manual from linux terminal, but stopped at "readonly partition"
I have not sufficient knowledge and no actual clear instructions.

Kingroot failed at about 70%, without any error messages.

Any idea or link to insruction highly welcome

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried KingRoot, you can download it from their website? Not 100% guaranteed but supports the most phones. Also you could try SuperSU's Update.zip too.

Comment: OP states that KingRoot fails. Also, there's likely no custom recovery available for such an unpopular device, so SuperSU might not be feasible.